# php-fpm/nginx Many Continuously Requests

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I'm using nginx/1.7.7 and here is config:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

worker_rlimit_nofile 300000;
events {
    multi_accept on;
    worker_connections  300000;
    use epoll;
}

http {

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile           on;
    tcp_nopush         on;
    tcp_nodelay        on;
    keepalive_timeout  15;
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    server {
        listen 80;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        root /var/www;
        server_tokens off;
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;


        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;

                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_keep_conn on;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my PHP-FPM Config (php 5.6.x)

```
rlimit_files = 6000
[www]
user = nginx
group = nginx
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 30000;
pm.process_idle_timeout = 1;
chdir = /
security.limit_extensions = .php
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_flag[display_startup_errors] = on
```

With my setup, i serve customers live video files (so the request should never end until the user stops the connection).

The problem here is that when many requests are being made / second, (something like contiously, you can call it flood), my **whole web server is becoming very slow** and i even **get many 504 gateway timeouts**. Some requests when flood is taking place, are not complete.

For example i**f 2000 requests are watching live streams** without flood, **everything is fine**, `but with flood`, `everything is becoming very very slow`, although the requests are not exceeded the 400-500 / second (but i repeat they are continuously )

My Server has 128 GB of RAM, and 38 cores. When the flood is taken place, my CPU does not even go to 10% which makes me wonder that if my CPU was reading at Full Speed, that problem shouldn't exists.

My RAM also is in very good levels when that happens. (Not even 10-15% use).

Is there something i'm missing? Maybe the sock (php5-fpm.sock) has some limits? Can we raise them?

Thank you
Regards

Comment: Thousands of live video streams? Have you considered *bandwidth* limitations?

Comment: I told already, that if there is no flood, my server can keep up with 2000 concurrent requests. The problem is that when my server is under a small Dos attack (300/400 requests / second) then that problem happens.

Comment: Have you checked bandwidth usage or not? Depending on the streaming tech you're using, new requests may use a bunch of bandwidth setting up the stream and fetching enough to start playback.